# How to transfer universe to another PC?

Tags: starbound

I played Starbound with friends and we have a homeplanet with our huge base on it. I want to keep all our progress when launch server on another PC.

It is possible to transfer universe to another PC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starbound saves your progress in two different folders; **players** and **universe**. Both of these are located in your main Starbound folder (in `linux32` or in `linux64` if you use Linux version).

The players folder stores your character, your inventory and your ship. The universe folder stores all the planets you've explored and any changes made to them.

If you want to transfer everything to another computer, just copy the content of both of these folders and paste it in the same location on the other computer.

Comment: And jut where exactly are those two folders please?