# How do I transfer Starbound characters from a Mac to a PC?

Tags: starbound

Would I need a usb and/or the computers to be side by side in order to transfer my characters? I want to transfer my characters from my mac to my pc.

Comment: Assuming you have starbound on steam, you can use cloud storage to share characters between both computers.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Are you sure Starbound supports Steam cloud synchronization? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: The location of your universe and characters for the Windows Steam version is `[Your Steam library directory]\SteamApps\common\Starbound\storage`. On Windows, you can just copy the whole directory. But I don't know the save location on Mac or Linux and I have no idea if the savegames are compatible between versions for different operating systems.

Comment: I definitely know that pseudorandom numbers generator differs between Mac and Windows -- that makes universes different and probably incompatible.

Comment: @Philipp I thought I'd read that in another question but now that I look through some more they all say to use dropbox to sync between computers. I found [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/153007/how-to-transfer-universe-to-another-pc?rq=1) which may be a duplicate but I don't know if there are any extra steps since this question asks about PC to Mac transfers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cloud service like Dropbox to backup your starbound saves folder.

I would suggest not replacing the universe saves from mac to windows or viceversa because they are not compatible due to the universe seed being different.

By moving your character home you should be able to access and use it.

As your world is not moved, you will need to store what you want to bring over in your inventory. Or try to copy also the ship files

Comment: If you are interested I have a bash script to link Dropbox to starbound save folder. So that you don't have to worry about syncing computers anymore or doing backups.